# Python: Comparing 2 sets of data, yield best match and match %

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-logic

I've seen lots of Q&A on this topic, but none contain the type of output I'm looking for.  Any words of wisdom on this would be very much appreciated!

- I have 2 lists... both lists contain 1 column, consisting of **Full Name|University** (i.e., name and university, concatenated, and separated by a pipe)
- There's not always an exact match, due to nicknames and university abbreviations.  I want to compare each record in list 1 with each record in list 2, and find the closest match.
- I then want to produce an output file with 3 columns:   Every item from list 1, The closest match from list 2, and the match %.

Does anyone have sample code they could share?  Thanks!

Comment: You probably won't get much help without showing some code you've tried, but the [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) is a nice library for this.

Comment: Try to explain the problem with Python types i.e _columns_ and _records_ are not Python data types and sound domain specific. As Jack recommended some code examples are always good.

Comment: I'm super new to Python -- any code I tried for this has bombed, so I thought I'd ask here.  Pardon my noob naming conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, here is an answer which can provide matches on either the full name or the university - you could extend it to include fuzzy search using a library like fuzzywuzzy:

1. For both lists, split each string into a [full name, university] list (if some of the strings don't contain the '|' character, you might need to wrap this in a `try, except` or an `if` statement):

   `new_list = [item.split('|') for item in old_list]`
2. Run the following command to match on either element (assuming that one list is called `list1` and the other list is called `list2`):

   `matches = [val for val in list1 for item in list2 if val[0] == item[0] or val[1] == item[1]]`